# spawn external program in the background inside a loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to stress-test (at a very basic level) a server by simulating multiple client programs with the following:

```
for i in {1..5} ; do echo ./client-program& ; done
```

but it fails with:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

How can I achieve the above and also store the `std:out` and `std::err` of each invoked instance of the "client-program" in separate files? (so that I may later `diff` them for equality).

Comment: Are you running this from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `;` is redundant, `&` already serves as a separator, so you don't need anything else. To capture stdout and stderr as well do:

```
for i in {1..5} ; do ./client-program > "$i.out" 2> "$i.err" & done
```

Comment: @stephanechazelas why are the quotes necessary here? `$i` will only ever be one of `1,2,3,4,5`, is it a compatibility thing?

Comment: And omitting the quotes around `$i` is still asking `bash` to split it (with the current value of `$IFS`) and perform globbing on it, which does not make sense here.